Derivative bounds for self convolution of the spherical measure in $R^d$
While reading this article on near $L^1$ estimates for the spherical lacunary maximal function, I came across the estimate
$$ |\partial^{\gamma} (\widetilde{\sigma} \ast \sigma)(x)| \lesssim |x|^{-(1 + |\gamma|)} \chi_{|x| \leq 2}(x) \qquad \text{for $\gamma \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{d}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$}.$$
Here, $\sigma$ is a measure on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, given by
$$\langle{\sigma, \phi}\rangle := \int \phi(y) \chi(y) d \theta(y),$$
with $\chi$ being a smooth function with a compact support contained inside a ball of radius $\leq 1/2$. Moreover, its refection $\widetilde{\sigma}$ is defined by the action
$$\langle{\widetilde{\sigma}, \phi}\rangle := \langle{\sigma, \tilde{\phi}}\rangle, \qquad \text{where} \qquad \tilde{\phi}(x) = \phi(-x).$$
The authors mention that the formula is a standard one, but I have been unable to find a reference or a proof. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Could you please explain what do you mean by a reflection of a measure?

@AlekseiKulikov, I have edited the question to include the definitions.

To be honest, now I am even more confused, as I do not seem to understand what is $\sigma$ (you say it is a measure on a sphere, but then talk about a function $\chi$ with a support in a ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$).

What is the meaning of $\partial^{\gamma} (\widetilde{\sigma} \ast \sigma)(x)$, given that $\widetilde{\sigma} \ast \sigma$ is a measure?

@AlekseiKulikov, sorry about the confusion. $d\theta$ is the standard spherical measure on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$. The purpose of $\chi$ is to localise the measure. If it is supported on a ball centered at the north pole with radius $\leq 1/2$, then we can see that $\sigma$ is supported on the half sphere. Does this clarify your doubt?

@IosifPinelis. I believe one can show that $\tilde{\sigma} \ast \sigma$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, and we are talking about its Radon--Nikodym derivative.

Is $\chi$ smooth?

@IosifPinelis yes. It is. I have added that in the question.
